# Figuring out where to add text in a MATLAB histogram

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I have a MATLAB histogram graph produced with some data, with some 50 bins. I now need to insert a line of text into the graph, at any place where it wouldn't tangle with the histogram bars. The text is basically 'Period of data used: mmm dd to mmm dd' (I mention this to give an idea of the width required and where the text can be split if necessary).

One method I considered was finding out a series of contiguous histogram bins where the freq (y axis) remains less than 90% of the maximum of all frequencies; then, the text can be printed at the x position starting at the first of those bins near the top of the graph.

Is this a good way of going about it? If so, how do I compute this contiguous series of bins without looping around?

Or is there a better way of placing this text adaptively according to the data?

Edit: Due to other considerations, the number of histogram bins is not a fixed 50 any more, but rather `xmax/20` where xmax is the maximum x-axis value. Algorithms that depend on working on aggregates of a number of bins might need to take this variability into account, when calculating that number.

Comment: Why don't you add the "text" as a title? It does not interfere with the histogram.

Comment: Because it isn't the title? There's already a title for the graph, and this is just some relevant data that will be useful when the plot is viewed as an image.

Comment: @sundar Do you have to do it programmatically? You can do it very easily interactively through the matlab figure window

Comment: The interactive way is feasible for now, due to very low volume of graphs generated (and a human eye does make this much easier and more reliable); it'll just be even better to have it autogenerated for the sake of future-proofing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way would be to use a multiline title, optionally along with TeX formatting to de-emphasise the additional info. To make a multiline title, pass a cell array of strings like this:

```
title({'\fontsize{16}Actual Title';'\fontsize{8}other info'})
```

Being consistent across the histograms, I think this would look tidier than having text on the graph itself that might move around.

Comment: I like the fontsize trick, this is a workable alternate in case the original idea turns out too difficult. Thanks!